# Restoring a text (known_hosts) file

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, data-recovery, restore

```
rm ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Without doing a backup of this file
Now file is empty, is there any way to recovery/restore this file ?

Comment: Not easily. Depends on the disk format used but you could use something like debugfs. Alternatively, you could use a recovery console and grep the actual disk file for the data you have lost.

Comment: The file will be re-populated as you connect to hosts again, albeit you will be unable to tell whether the host key of the remote machine was changed since you last connected.

Answer (score 0):

So you could potentially recover the text from the file, if you can remember a unique string that appears in it.

The below command will print 100 lines before and after the pattern match(`-B 100 -A 100`).  Try and remember something that appears in the file, this is not guaranteed to work, but it could recover the contents.

```
grep -a -B 100 -A 100 'some unique string in the file' /dev/sda1 > results.txt
```

`/dev/sda1` is the partition of the disk that the file resides on, change this as appropriate. The `-a` tells grep to treat the hard disk as a text file. Try and remember a unique string in the file and change that to suit.

Answer (score 0):

not a generic answer, but about `known_hosts`, you can use `ssh-keyscan`

as per man `ssh-keyscan`

> It was designed to aid in building and verifying ssh_known_hosts files.

This implies you know hosts you connect to.